# What is the NASM equivalent to '_TEXT SEGMENT' used in MASM?

Tags: assembly, nasm, masm

The MSVC compiles `Test.c` into assembly with the command `CL Test.c /Fa`

```c
// Test.c
void test() {int var = 123}
void main() {int var = 321}
```

And this is the resulting assembly code.

```
; Test.asm
_TEXT   SEGMENT
var$ = 0
main    PROC
    sub rsp, 24
    mov DWORD PTR var$[rsp], 321
    xor eax, eax
    add rsp, 24
    ret 0
main    ENDP
_TEXT   ENDS

_TEXT   SEGMENT
var$ = 0
test    PROC
    sub rsp, 24
    mov DWORD PTR var$[rsp], 123
    add rsp, 24
    ret 0
test    ENDP
_TEXT   ENDS
```

I don't know the `var$ = 0` and `mov DWORD PTR var$[rsp], 123` syntax in NASM. What is the equivalent code in NASM?

Comment: You can omit the segment stuff, but otherwise it's `section _text`. `var$=0` is `var$ equ 0` (if nasm accepts `$` in symbols) and the `mov DWORD PTR var$[rsp], 123` is `mov dword [var$+rsp], 123`

Comment: Is the `section _text` specific to each label or global? Because `_TEXT SEGMENT` is specific to each `PROC` and two different `_TEXT SEGMENT` can contain the same value (`var$` in the MASM case). Can a `section _text` do the same?

Comment: That's not related to segments as those variables are just assembly time constants (I believe you have already been told that). No, nasm does not allow `equ` defined constant to be changed.

Comment: You can instead use `%assign var$ 0` as that is changeable.

Comment: I understand that they are assembly time constant. I tried to translate the given MASM assembly code to NASM assembly code, but could not get it to work. I am unsure if it is just MASM convention to declare variables identifiers as assembly time constants or if it's also in NASM/other assemblers

Comment: `mov DWORD [var$ + rsp], 123` is valid NASM syntax (if it allows `$` in symbol names).

Comment: @PeterCordes Sory to bother you, but many years later i have a pretty ignorant question. Why would it make [0 + rsp] instead of just [rsp]  is it just end up being sort of inline documentation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Beeeaaar: Just "inline documentation" to describe the semantic meaning of the `0`.  The actual machine code would use `[rsp]` with no displacement.  If you had more than one variable, the others would have non-zero offsets from that anchor point in the stack frame.